# Why my vite config taking his own url as proxy instead of given?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, proxy, config, vite

**Vite config**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
 
 // https://vitejs.dev/config/
 
export default defineConfig({   plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: '@', replacement: '/src' }
    ],   
  },   
  // ...
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
      "/api": { 
        target: "https://truthgate-backend.vercel.app" },
        https: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/app/, ''),
      
      }
   },
})
```

[image: my browser output of application]

Comment: I think it should work if you remove the misplaced curly brace in the line with the `target`key.